# How best to instantiate execution contexts?

Tags: multithreading, scala, scala-2.11

I'm building a library that others--i.e. those uninterested in internals--could use to pull data from our DBs. In the internals, I want a couple I/O calls to be performed in parallel for performance purposes. The trade-off here is that the client (who, again, might not care much about this whole threading thing) would need to provide an appropriate execution context. Therefore, I provide a suggestion to use a helpful execution context in a helper object:

```
object ThreadPoolHelper {
  val cachedThreadPoolContext: ExecutionContext =
    ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())
}
```

The question is (assuming that someday I also provide other options, like, say, a fixed thread pool for the clients to optionally use) am I fine just leaving this (these) as a val? Or am I better off making it lazy? Or a def?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way or another, lazy is the way to go.

Making them `lazy val`s would be a good all-purpose choice, as each could be initialized as needed (as they are accessed). Then, you would never initialize more thread pools than are needed. `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` is an `implicit lazy val`.

Technically, singleton objects (like `ThreadPoolHelper`) are lazy by default, so they will not be initialized until they are first accessed. A val would be fine if you only had one `ExecutionContext` in an `object`. However, multiple `ExecutionContext`s as vals in the same object wouldn't make as much sense, because accessing one would initialize them all--which would use more resources than needed.

A `def` would not make sense, because then you would be creating a new `ExecutionContext` on each call, and throwing it away when done. That could cause a lot of unwanted overhead, and default the purpose of having a thread pool in the first place.

Some `ExecutionContext`s that are little more custom than yours are singleton `object`s that extend `ExecutionContext` and implement their own custom behavior. These would also be lazy.